# Can you put int variable into string in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, variables

Can you put an integer from a variable, for example:

```
int i=17;
char array[]= i;
```

and now i want to have

```
array[3]= {1,7,\0}
```

I know it doesn't work this way but i dont know how to do it without some special functions, which i dont want to use. Thank you for your help.

this is what i came up with:

```
char array[];
    int counter = 172; //the number i want to put into string
    int i= 0;
    int p=0;
    float c = counter;
    int k=0, g=0, h=0;

    while(counter !=0){
        counter = counter /10;
        c= c/10;    
        p++;
    }
    while(p !=0){
        c=c*10;
        k=c;
        h= k-g;
        g=k*10;
        array[i] = h;
        i++;
        p--;
    }
    array[i]= '\0';
```

Comment: Using a float is both overkill and error-prone. Those "special functions" you want to avoid for whatever reason get the digits of an integer with a simple %10. Given an integer x, x%10 is its rightmost digit. Then divide it by 10 (x /= 10) to strip that digit, and get the next, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sprintf(buffer, "%d", i);`

Make sure that `buffer` is long enough to contain any possible number-string *and the terminating `\0` byte.*

`sprintf` accepts everything that `printf` does, but sends its output to a string buffer instead of STDOUT.

Comment: is it possible to do without functions like sprintf and log ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the function I suggested in my answer. Instead of using log10, you can write a loop that divids the number by 10 and counts how many times the loop ran until the number became 0

Comment: But how do I isolate all the counted numbers into a its own index in an char array?

Comment: I should not use any library functions is my problem

Comment: I thought of an solution. Do you think it is correct?

Comment: @DávidSlota I think your program doesn't work. The result will be an empty string. There are few logical bugs that causing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use sprintf, then here is a sample code snippet for you.

```
    #define BASE 10
    #define MAXLEN 10
    int val = 153;
    char valstr[MAXLEN];

    //Reverse the int
    int valcpy = val;
    int valrev = 0;
    while(valcpy) {
        valrev *= BASE;
        valrev += valcpy % BASE;
        valcpy /= BASE;
    }

    //Convert to string
    int i = 0;
    while(valrev) {
        valstr[i] = valrev % BASE + '0';
        valrev /= BASE;
        i++;
    }
    valstr[i] = '\0';

    printf("%d = %s", val, valstr); //prints 153 = 153
```